# before destroy on associated model update, errors not propagating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a parent model, that is being updated via params like '@client.update_attributes(params[:client]'.  In my params is a call to destroy a 'client_card'.  I have a before_destroy method on the client_card that prevents it from being destroyed etc. My before_destroy method is working, however, the errors on the before_destroy do not propagate to the related model when updated.  Any advice on how to propagate this model error to the associated model when updated?

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_cards, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_associated :client_cards

class ClientCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, :foreign_key => 'client_id'

  attr_accessible :id, :client_id, :card_hash, :last_four, :exp_date

  before_destroy :check_relationships

  def check_finished_appointments
    appointments = Appointment.select { |a| a.client_card == self && !a.has_started }
    if(appointments && appointments.length > 0 )
      errors.add(:base, "This card is tied to an appointment that hasn't occurred yet.")
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `validates_associated` is only running the explicitly-declared validations for `ClientCard`, and won't trigger off the errors you added in the `before_destroy` callback.  Your best option might be a `before_update` callback on `Client`:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_cards, :dependent => :destroy

  before_update :check_client_cards

  # stuff

  def check_client_cards
    if client_cards.any_future_appointments?
      errors.add(:base, "One or more client cards has a future appointment.")
    end
  end
end
```

Then on `ClientCard`:

```
class ClientCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, :foreign_key => 'client_id'

  # stuff

  def self.any_future_appointments?
    all.detect {|card| !card.check_finished_appointments }
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to prevent the Client from being updated if it has client_cards with future appointments, but I do want to prevent the Client from updating if that update includes a destroy on it's nested attribute of a client_card.. then I want to throw an error if that client_card has future appointments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it is working? If your controller's delete action is redirecting to index  as it typically does, you will never see the error since the model is reloaded by the redirect.

Comment: no.. I have stepped through with the debugger.  this isn't on client_card's delete, it is in the parent model's (client) controller's update method.  client.update_params is called, and client has no errors (even though the params say to destroy an associated object e.g. client_card)